# Looping GM_xmlhttpRequest gives "TypeError Null" on a variable

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, typeerror, gm-xmlhttprequest

I have some links in a page. I want to count the responses of each link and insert the numbers in front of the links. Here is what I have:

```
var links = document.evaluate('..../td[1]/font//a[@href]', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
var headings = document.evaluate('.../td[1]',document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)
for(var i = 0; i < links.snapshotLength; i++){
  var urls = links.snapshotItem(i).href;
  GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: 'GET',
    url: urls,
    onload function (res){
      var dt = document.implementation.createDocumentType("html", 
          "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN", "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd");
          doc = document.implementation.createDocument('', '', dt);
          html = doc.createElement('html');
          html.innerHTML = res.responseText;
          doc.appendChild(html);
      var responses = doc.evaluate('.../tr', doc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
      var nResponse = responses.snapshotLength - 1;
      var numResponse = document.createElement('font');
      numResponse.innerHTML = 
       '<b>' + nResponse +
       '</b>' ;
      headings.snapshotItem(i).parentNode.insertBefore(numResponse, headings.snapshotItem(i));
    }
  });
}
```

And I got the error message:

> TypeError: headings.snapshotItem(...) is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 3 problems:

1. Trying to pass a value to `GM_xmlhttpRequest`'s onload without a closure.
2. Looping on `links`, but trying to index `headings`.
3. Missing colon after the `onload` property.

(1) `GM_xmlhttpRequest` operates asynchronously.  Which means by the time `onload` fires that the variables `i` and `headings` will either be undefined or will be their ultimate value, not the loop value you want.

To pass a value to `onload`, use [a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/331508). (In the code below, `parseURL` provides the closure.)

(2) The variable `i` is looping on `links`, but the code is trying to use it to index `headings`!   It is very unlikely that there are the same number of each (and poor practice, even if there are).  Is the "heading" always a parent of the link?  If so use that.

Putting it all together, use code like this:

```
var links = document.evaluate (
    '..../td[1]/font//a[@href]', document, null, 
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null
);
//-- "Headings" are relative to links

for (var J = links.snapshotLength - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    var targUrl = links.snapshotItem (J).href;
    parseURL (targUrl, J);
}

function parseURL (targUrl, J) {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
        method: 'GET',
        url:    targUrl,
        onload: function (res) {
            var dt = document.implementation.createDocumentType (
                "html", "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN", 
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"
            );
            var doc         = document.implementation.createDocument ('', '', dt);
            var html        = doc.createElement ('html');
            html.innerHTML  = res.responseText;
            doc.appendChild (html);

            var responses = doc.evaluate (
                '.../tr', doc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null
            );
            var nResponse = responses.snapshotLength - 1;
            var numResponse = document.createElement ('font');
            numResponse.innerHTML = '<b>' + nResponse + '</b>';

            var heading     = links.snapshotItem (J).parentNode.parentNode;
            heading.parentNode.insertBefore (numResponse, heading);
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: One more question, after I add these numbers to the page. The page loads very slowly.Is there anyway to speed up? run-at document-start can execute code before the page loaded but I still have some stuff to run at document-end.

Comment: You may need to open a new question.  In general: make sure not using GM_xmlhttpRequest in synch mode (it's off by default); make sure you're not running in iframes, unnecessarily; restrict processed links; start script after window load; Don't use XPath on the AJAX results.